Question on the Fourier transform of the Faddeeva function $w(z)$
Mathematica indicates the Fourier transform of the Faddeeva function
$$w(z)=e^{-z^2}\, \text{erfc}(-i z)\tag{1}$$
is
$$\hat{w}(\xi)=\mathcal{F}_z[w(z)](\xi)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(z)\, e^{-i 2 \pi \xi z} \, dz=\frac{e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \left(3 \pi+i \left(-\log\left(4 \xi^4\right)+2 \log(\xi)+2 \log(2 i \xi)\right)+2 i\, \text{Ei}\left(\pi^2 \xi^2\right)\right)\\=\frac{e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(\pi +i\, \text{Ei}\left(\pi^2 \xi^2\right)\right)\tag{2}$$
but I don't believe this is correct.

Figure (1) below illustrates the real and imaginary parts of the the Faddeeva function $w(z)$
are even and odd respectively, whereas Figure (2) below illustrates the real and imaginary parts of $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above are both even, but I believe $\hat{w}(\xi)$ should actually be strictly real and look somewhat similar to the approximation illustrated in Figure (3) below.


Figure (1): Illustration of formula (1) for $\Re(w(z))$ and $\Im(w(z))$ in blue and orange


Figure (2): Illustration of formula (2) for $\Re(\hat{w}(\xi))$ and $\Im(\hat{w}(\xi))$ in blue and orange


Figure (3): Illustration of approximation of $\hat{w}(\xi)=\mathcal{F}_z[w(z)](\xi)$ recovered from formula (1) for $w(z)$

The red discrete evaluation points in Figures (2) and (3) above are at $(0,\sqrt{\pi})$ which is based on the real part of formula (2) above evaluated at $\xi=0$.

The Fourier transform of $w(z)$ can be evaluated as
$$\mathcal{F}_z[w(z)](\xi)=\mathcal{F}_z[\Re(w(z))](\xi)+\mathcal{F}_z[i\, \Im(w(z))](\xi)\tag{3}$$
and I believe
$$\mathcal{F}_z[\Re(w(z))](\xi)=\sqrt{\pi}\, e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}\tag{4}$$
which is consistent with the real part of formula (2) above illustrated as the blue curve in Figure (2) above, but I believe $\mathcal{F}_z[i\, \Im(w(z))](\xi)$ should be a real odd function and look somewhat similar to the approximation illustrated in Figure (4) below.


Figure (4): Illustration of approximation of $\mathcal{F}_z[i\, \Im(w(z))](\xi)$ recovered from formula (1) for $\Im(w(z))$


Question: What is the actual Fourier transform of the Faddeeva function $w(z)$?


Searching with Google for "Fourier transform of Faddeeva function" the AI Overview indicates "The Fourier transform of the Faddeeva function (also known as the complex error function) does not have a simple, closed-form expression", but I'm hoping there are enough clues in this question to derive a closed-form expression for the Fourier transform of $w(z)$ assuming its really unknown.

The plots in Figures (3) and (4) above were evaluated using the nested Fourier series representation in formula (5) in my MathOverflow question on the Fourier inversion theorem. The small-scale $8$-hertz oscillation in the plots is a function of using $N=20$ and $f=8$ as the evaluation limits for formula (5) in my MathOverflow question, and I believe this small-scale oscillation goes away as $N, f\to\infty$.

Noting that Figure (3) in my question above seems to imply
$$\mathcal{F}_x[i\, \Im(w(z))](\xi)\approx\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\mathcal{F}_x[\Re(w(z))](\xi) & \xi<0 \\
 \mathcal{F}_x[\Re(w(z))](\xi) & \xi>0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$
except perhaps for $\xi$ very close to zero lead me to the conjecture that the Fourier transform of $w(z)$ is actually
$$\hat{w}(\xi)=\mathcal{F}_z[w(z)](\xi)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(z)\, e^{-i 2 \pi \xi z} \, dz=\sqrt{\pi}\, e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}\, (\text{sgn}(\xi)+1)\tag{2}.$$

Figure (1) below illustrates $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above where the red discrete evaluation point is at $(0, \sqrt{\pi})$.

Figure (1): Illustration of $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2)

Figures (2) and (3) below illustrate the real and imaginary parts of the Faddeeva function $w(z)$ recovered from $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above using formula (5) in my MathOverflow question on the Fourier inversion theorem where formula (5) is evaluated at $N=20$ and $f=4$. Figures (2) and (3) below seem consistent with the conjectured Fourier transform $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above.


Figure (2): Illustration of $\Re(w(z))$ recovered from formula (2) for $\hat{w}(\xi)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function $\Re(w(z))$


Figure (3): Illustration of $\Im(w(z))$ recovered from formula (2) for $\hat{w}(\xi)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function $\Im(w(z))$

Mathematica indicates the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above is
$$\mathcal{F}_{\xi }^{-1}\left[\hat{w}(\xi)\right](z)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\pi}\, e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}\, (\text{sgn}(\xi)+1)\, e^{i 2 \pi z \xi} \, dz=e^{-z^2}+\frac{2 i}{\sqrt{\pi}}\, F(z)=w(z)\tag{3}$$
where $F(z)$ is the Dawson function which also seems to validate the conjectured Fourier transform $\hat{w}(\xi)$ defined in formula (2) above.
